# Change pattern by a path pattern with /

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file.txt with a lot of line inside such as::

```
blastdbcmd -db /path/path/LO/db_lh/makedb_KO -entry scaffold_2731 -range 32270-32509-strand minus >> file.fst
blastdbcmd -db /path/path/LO/db_lh/makedb_lKO -entry scaffold_2781 -range 3230-3508-strand minus >> file.fst
etc.
```

And I would like replace all `file.fst` pattern by `path/data/path/LO/file.txt`

and then get:

```
blastdbcmd -db /path/path/LO/db_lh/makedb_KO -entry scaffold_2731 -range 32270-32509-strand minus >> path/data/path/LO/file.txt
blastdbcmd -db /path/path/LO/db_lh/makedb_lKO -entry scaffold_2781 -range 3230-3508-strand minus >> path/data/path/LO/file.txt

etc.
```

It tried :

```
sed -i -e 's/file.fst/path/data/path/LO/file.txt/g' /path/path/file_script_recover_copie.txt
```

But it does not work, someone has a better idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with `awk` then you could try following.

```
awk -v val="path/data/path/LO/file.txt" '{sub("file.fst",val)} 1' Input_file
```

Pass path's value to `-v val` variable of `awk` and then it should work.

With `sed` in case you want to keep delimiter as `/` itself then try following.(I am escaping `\/` in `sed` solution so that it will NOT be considered as it is used for closing `sed`'s block)

```
sed 's/file.fst/path\/data\/path\/LO\/file.txt/'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Backup your file(s), and try this:

```
sed -i -e 's@file.fst@path/data/path/LO/file.txt@g' /path/path/file_script_recover_copie.txt
```

Eg:

```
$ cat file
blastdbcmd -db /path/path/LO/db_lh/makedb_KO -entry scaffold_2731 -range 32270-32509-strand minus >> file.fst
blastdbcmd -db /path/path/LO/db_lh/makedb_lKO -entry scaffold_2781 -range 3230-3508-strand minus >> file.fst
etc.

$ sed -e 's@file.fst@path/data/path/LO/file.txt@g' file
blastdbcmd -db /path/path/LO/db_lh/makedb_KO -entry scaffold_2731 -range 32270-32509-strand minus >> path/data/path/LO/file.txt
blastdbcmd -db /path/path/LO/db_lh/makedb_lKO -entry scaffold_2781 -range 3230-3508-strand minus >> path/data/path/LO/file.txt
etc.
```

The problem is because your replacement has `/` in it, where `/` also is your `sed`'s `s` delimiter. But `sed` can use other characters as `s`'s delimiter. So I changed it to `@`.
(You can use others too, so long they're in right places)

Another way is to escape `/`, by adding `\`before it, so inside `s` they become `\/. 
(This applies to other special characters too, for example to use`'`you can put`\'` inside.)

Comment: Just to add to this: the first character after the `s` defines the delimiter in the substitution expression, it doesn't have to be `/`.

Comment: It did work thank you :) so the `@`  allows to take into account the `/// `patterned right?

Comment: Kudos for your string of recent answers, but please refrain from answering questions which are obvious and clear duplicates. There's a good collection of shell scripting canonicals in the [Stack Overflow `bash` tag info page](/tags/bash/info).

Comment: @tripleee  Okay, got it. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Sure thing! If you'd like to coordinate canonicals etc, there's a link to a Stack Overflow Bash chat room where I hang out.